# Is it possible (theoretically) for the evm to have a stack overflow with deep nested contract calls?

Tags: solidity, evm

Does this feasibly never happen before the transaction gas limit or something? Theoretically if the evm has a stack there must be some amount of calls that would overflow it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EVM stack has 1024 slots available and every time a function calls another function, it reserves some space on the stack to store arguments, return values and local variables. The deeper is the call chain, the more slots you need and you eventually run out of slots if you go too deep

Comment: Interesting. Is one slot taken up by one variable/parameter, or one function call?